# Flutter Riverpod: How to create different instances of the same provider for each Stateful widget on a GridView

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have a GridView which contains a list of **StatefulWidgets** that shows a preview of the image being uploaded and the progress of the upload for that image.

Each widget on the list **should have its own state** where some of them can upload successfully and others may fail, so the user can retry only those images that failed to upload.

The problem is:

Riverpod is only able to create an instance and that same instance is shared over the whole project. So, if I use Riverpod to track the state of each image, all images on the GridView will share the same state instead of each one have its own state.

Is there a way to use the same provider, but instead of get the same instance every time I call **context.read(provider)** or **watch(provider.state)** I get a new independent and fresh one?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're looking for the `.family` modifier. See the docs [here](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/modifiers/family). You could pass an id or key as the parameter to your StateProvider.

For example:

```dart
final imageProvider = StateProvider.family<ImageModel, String>((ref, id) => ...);
```

Comment: I don't think so. family just let me pass an argument while getting the provider. What I need is to generate differente instances of the same provider so each widget on the list can deal with its own state.

See it like a ListView where each ListTile has its own StateNotifierProvider.

Comment: The argument is what you could use to make the different instances of the same provider, though. You could also have the family provider interacting with a StateNotifier that holds state that is common to all the items.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After read the docs again I was able to rethink my implementation and you were right about using family.

Comment: Look into other [solution](https://github.com/rajeshbbalam/flutter_riverpod_multi_instance),by overriding provider with in the ProviderScope.