# Scope a Provider to multiple instances

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have an `isLoading` `StateNotifierProvider` to add a loading indicator to my buttons when they are tapped until the async method has completed.

However, when I have two buttons visible at once, they both show the indicator when only one was tapped.

How do I scope the StateNotifierProvider to one instance per button instead of one instance for all buttons?

Button:

```
class AsyncSubmitButton extends ConsumerWidget {
  AsyncSubmitButton(
      {required this.text,
      required this.onPressed})
      : super(key: key);

  final String text;
  final Future<void> Function() onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    final isLoading = watch(isLoadingProvider);
    final form = ReactiveForm.of(context)!;
    return ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: form.invalid
            ? null
            : () => context.read(isLoadingProvider.notifier).pressed(onPressed),
        child: isLoading
            ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
            : Text(text),
        );
  }
}
```

Provider:

```
final isLoadingProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<AsyncSubmitButtonLoadingStateNotifier, bool>((ref) {
  return AsyncSubmitButtonLoadingStateNotifier(isLoading: false);
});

class AsyncSubmitButtonLoadingStateNotifier extends StateNotifier<bool> {
  AsyncSubmitButtonLoadingStateNotifier({required bool isLoading})
      : super(isLoading);

  dynamic pressed(Future<void> Function() onPressedFunction) async {
    state = true;
    try {
      await onPressedFunction();
    } catch (error) {
      state = false;
    } finally {
      state = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67095295/3935156), and also [this answer](https://github.com/rrousselGit/river_pod/issues/231#issuecomment-736170050) suggest, use the [family modifier](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/modifiers/family). This question is borderline a duplicate of the question in the linked answer but I found this use case was not documented well (only in SO/GitHub answers) and I think this answer is more full so want to leave this here.

The state of a provider is always shared globally. But you can access that state with a passed in `id` by using the `family` modifier, and then compare the `id` when reading the provider to see if it is the corresponding instance. Remember to use `.autoDispose` when using `family` to prevent memory leaks. I think it might create a new reference to the provider with the passed in param for each read with a different passed in param, and providers are never disposed unless using the `autoDispose` modifier.

So the code in the question becomes:

Button:

```
class AsyncSubmitButton extends ConsumerWidget {
  AsyncSubmitButton(
      {required this.text,
      this.id = 'global',
      required this.onPressed})
      : super(key: key);

  final String text;
  final Future<void> Function() onPressed;
  final String id;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    final isLoading = watch(isLoadingProvider(id)) &&
        id == context.read(isLoadingProvider(id).notifier).id;
    final form = ReactiveForm.of(context)!;
    return ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: form.invalid
            ? null
            : () => context.read(isLoadingProvider.notifier).pressed(onPressed),
        child: isLoading
            ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
            : Text(text),
        );
  }
}
```

Provider:

```
final isLoadingProvider = StateNotifierProvider.family
    .autoDispose<AsyncSubmitButtonLoadingStateNotifier, bool, String>(
        (ref, id) {
  return AsyncSubmitButtonLoadingStateNotifier(isLoading: false, id: id);
});

class AsyncSubmitButtonLoadingStateNotifier extends StateNotifier<bool> {
  AsyncSubmitButtonLoadingStateNotifier(
      {required bool isLoading, required this.id})
      : super(isLoading);

  String id;

  dynamic onPressed(Future<void> Function() onPressedFunction) async {
    state = true;
    try {
      await onPressedFunction();
    } catch (error) {
      state = false;
    } finally {
      state = false;
    }
  }
}
```

And in the widget, if you don't care about it being unique, just don't pass the `id`, and it'll default. If you do care, since you have 2 unique buttons using it etc, specify the `id`...

```
child: AsyncSubmitButton(text: 'Sign Out', id: 'signOutButton', onPressed: vm.signOut)
```